# How can I access my web server mounted with virtualbox in my pc from internet?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, dns, webserver

I have a web server with virtualbox in my pc, but I require that it can be seen from the internet, entering with the domain name that i have.

I have a fixed ip address and a domain name with godaddy.

I do not know how I can make my web server can be working and that when I enter a web address (the domain that I have contracted) show my web page.

Thank you

Comment: Port forwarding of ports 80 and 443 from your router to the VirtualBox (just like any internal server). Also, if the VirtualBox is NAT rather than bridged, **it** has to have port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Either have virtualbox port forward port 80 to your vm, or run the vm in bridged mode. Then, on your home (ADSL?) router add a port forwarding rule to map port 80 on the WAN side to the internal LAN ip address of your computer that's running the vm (if in nat mode) or to the vm's ip address (if running in bridged mode).

Test this with your public ip address first before trying to get the domain name to work.

For the DNS to work, have a www address in your DNS zones to map to your public ip address.